# Global memoizing fetch() to prevent multiple of the same request

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch

I have an SPA and for technical reasons I have different elements potentially firing the same `fetch()` call pretty much at the same time.[1]

Rather than going insane trying to prevent multiple unrelated elements to orchestrate loading of elements, I am thinking about creating a gloabalFetch() call where:

- the `init` argument is serialised (along with the `resource` parameter) and used as hash
- when a request is made, it's queued and its hash is stored
- when another request comes, and the hash matches (which means it's in-flight), another request will NOT be made, and it will piggy back from the previous one

```
async function globalFetch(resource, init) {
  const sigObject = { ...init, resource }
  const sig = JSON.stringify(sigObject)

  // If it's already happening, return that one
  if (globalFetch.inFlight[sig]) {

  // NOTE: I know I don't yet have sig.timeStamp, this is just to show
  // the logic
  if (Date.now - sig.timeStamp < 1000 * 5) {  
    return globalFetch.inFlight[sig]
  } else {
    delete globalFetch.inFlight[sig]
  }

  const ret = globalFetch.inFlight[sig] = fetch(resource, init)
  return ret
}
globalFetch.inFlight = {}
```

It's obviously missing a way to have the requests' timestamps. Plus, it's missing a way to delete old requests in batch. Other than that... is this a good way to go about it?

Or, is there something already out there, and I am reinventing the wheel...?

[1] If you are curious, I have several location-aware elements which will reload data independently based on the URL. It's all nice and decoupled, except that it's a little... too decoupled. Nested elements (with partially matching URLs) needing the same data potentially end up making the same request at the same time.

Comment: If these are GET requests, the browser automatically caches them.

Comment: ...? Only if the server allows, and it won't happen for API requests...

Comment: "it won't happen for API requests" you mean POST requests? Otherwise yes it sounds like you are reinventing the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), with the difference that you would need to handle cases where new requests are made even before the response is available, which could be done by waiting for the previous request do end before trying to start a new one: https://jsfiddle.net/852tzcjd/ however only GET requests are cacheable.

Comment: You are missing the most important use case -- where I could request `/something`, then `/somethingElse` and then `/something` again. Using the caches object is probably a good idea, but the implementation you propose won't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yv3m9x0n/1/

Comment: Plus I encourage you to use async/await, using promises is pure violence against code readability

Comment: The problem of my "implementation" in yourfiddle's use is that your request throws and it doesn't handle that, but that's not complicated to implement, given a properly defined expected behavior. If both requests worked, then my "implementation" would too: https://jsfiddle.net/p1ngr5jw/ (and I encourage you to @nickname people when you want them to see your responses)

Comment: @Kaiido Here is the final implementation in literate code, if you are interested. https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/spa-fetch/blob/master/spa-fetch.js

Comment: @Kaiido The repository has cypress tests too, it handles (and caches) every corner case of use of `fetch()` as well as network connections https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/spa-fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept will generally work just fine.

Some thing missing from your implementation:

1. Failed responses should either not be cached in the first place or removed from the cache when you see the failure.  And failure is not just rejected promises, but also any request that doesn't return an appropriate success status (probably a 2xx status).
2. `JSON.stringify(sigObject)` is not a canonical representation of the exact same data because properties might not be stringified in the same order depending upon how the `sigObject` was built.  If you grabbed the properties, sort them and inserted them in sorted order onto a temporary object and then stringified that, it would be more canonical.
3. I'd recommend using a `Map` object instead of a regular object for `globalFetch.inFlight` because it's more efficient when you're adding/removing items regularly and will never have any name collision with property names or methods (though your hash would probably not conflict anyway, but it's still a better practice to use a `Map` object for this kind of thing).
4. Items should be aged from the cache (as you apparently know already).  You can just use a `setInterval()` that runs every so often (it doesn't have to run very often - perhaps every 30 minutes) that just iterates through all the items in the cache and removes any that are older than some amount of time.  Since you're already checking the time when you find one, you don't have to clean the cache very often - you're just trying to prevent non-stop build-up of stale data that isn't going to be re-requested - so it isn't getting automatically replaced with newer data and isn't being used from the cache.
5. If you have any case insensitive properties or values in the request parameters or the URL, the current design would see different case as different requests.  Not sure if that matters in your situation or not or if it's worth doing anything about it.
6. When you write the real code, you need `Date.now()`, not `Date.now`.

Here's a sample implementation that implements all of the above (except for case sensitivity because that's data-specific):

```
function makeHash(url, obj) {
    // put properties in sorted order to make the hash canonical
    // the canonical sort is top level only, 
    //    does not sort properties in nested objects
    let items = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));
    // add URL on the front
    items.unshift(url);
    return JSON.stringify(items);
}

async function globalFetch(resource, init = {}) {
    const key = makeHash(resource, init);

    const now = Date.now();
    const expirationDuration = 5 * 1000;
    const newExpiration = now + expirationDuration;

    const cachedItem = globalFetch.cache.get(key);
    // if we found an item and it expires in the future (not expired yet)
    if (cachedItem && cachedItem.expires >= now) {
        // update expiration time
        cachedItem.expires = newExpiration;
        return cachedItem.promise;
    }

    // couldn't use a value from the cache
    // make the request
    let p = fetch(resource, init);
    p.then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            // if response not OK, remove it from the cache
            globalFetch.cache.delete(key);
        }
    }, err => {
        // if promise rejected, remove it from the cache
        globalFetch.cache.delete(key);
    });
    // save this promise (will replace any expired value already in the cache)
    globalFetch.cache.set(key, { promise: p, expires: newExpiration });
    return p;
}
// initalize cache
globalFetch.cache = new Map();

// clean up interval timer to remove expired entries
// does not need to run that often because .expires is already checked above
// this just cleans out old expired entries to avoid memory increasing
// indefinitely
globalFetch.interval = setInterval(() => {
    const now = Date.now()
    for (const [key, value] of globalFetch.cache) {
        if (value.expires < now) {
            globalFetch.cache.delete(key);
        }
    }
}, 10 * 60 * 1000); // run every 10 minutes
```

**Implementation Notes:**

1. Depending upon your situation, you may want to customize the cleanup interval time.  This is set to run a cleanup pass every 10 minutes just to keep it from growing unbounded.  If you were making millions of requests, you'd probably run that interval more often or cap the number of items in the cache.  If you aren't making that many requests, this can be less frequent.  It is just to clean up old expired entries sometime so they don't accumulate forever if never re-requested.  The check for the expiration time in the main function already keeps it from using expired entries - that's why this doesn't have to run very often.
2. This looks as `response.ok` from the `fetch()` result and promise rejection to determine a failed request.  There could be some situations where you want to customize what is and isn't a failed request with some different criteria than that.  For example, it might be useful to cache a 404 to prevent repeating it within the expiration time if you don't think the 404 is likely to be transitory.  This really depends upon your specific use of the responses and behavior of the specific host you are targeting.  The reason to not cache failed results is for cases where the failure is transitory (either a temporary hiccup or a timing issue and you want a new, clean request to go if the previous one failed).
3. There is a design question for whether you should or should not update the `.expires` property in the cache when you get a cache hit.  If you do update it (like this code does), then an item could stay in the cache a long time if it keeps getting requested over and over before it expires.  But, if you really want it to only be cached for a maximum amount of time and then force a new request, you can just remove the update of the expiration time and let the original result expire.  I can see arguments for either design depending upon the specifics of your situation.  If this is largely invariant data, then you can just let it stay in the cache as long as it keeps getting requested.  If it is data that can change regularly, then you may want it to be cached no more than the expiration time, even if its being requested regularly.

Comment: Most of this answer is IMO good advice, but I would argue against setInterval as a cache cleaning method (because it introduces something to manage in terms of memory, and it might result in a memory leak), and instead check the longevity of the item being used (perhaps, as an extra property of the cached value) and replace said value with a new one when the value is older than a set amount of time.

That way, you don't have to mantain long running processes, and it's just an extra IF statement.

Comment: @spersico - The OP is already checking the longevity of the item being used (that's right in their code already shown as a partial intended implementation).  The point of the interval is that unused, expired items have to get cleaned up at some point (which doesn't have to be very frequently and can be independent of the allowable cache interval because of the longevity check) to avoid the possibility of infinitely growing cache.  Running a clean every once in a while just keeps the cache from growing infinitely large over time, populated by lots of infrequently used and expired cache items.

Comment: @spersico - Besides, how does `setInterval()` possibly introduce memory leak liability?  You walk the cache, check each item, remove the ones that are expired and retain nothing other than what isn't expired and stays in the cache.

Comment: when you have setInterval you basically have a long running process that needs to be run. Where do you start the setInterval() in a way that you can kill it later? How do you avoid running setInterval() many times? When do you start running a setInterval?

Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that it's wrong to use setInterval, I'm just saying that IMO, if you can solve it with an if statement and replacing the old value, you probably should.

Comment: @spersico - I think you're a bit confused about what a `setInterval()` does.  It doesn't cause any web page to run any longer than it otherwise would and it doesn't by itself cause any memory leaks.  The OP already has an `if` statement on the time and is ALREADY checking that.  That's fine.

Comment: @spersico - But, you can't let old values that are never requested again sit in the cache forever unless the volume of requests is so small that the memory usage by expired entries doesn't matter.   But, if it does matter, then it could continue to grow memory usage indefinitely over time so you need to clean up old values and get rid of them.  Those expired values can be iterated and discovered either with a timer or when a new request is made.  Either one will do.  The timer limits the cleanup work to potentially be far less often which is more efficient.

Comment: @Merc - Added sample implementation that implements all the items in my list except any case insensitivity (because that is data-specific and we don't know what the data is).

Comment: @Merc - Just sounded like a fun problem to attack.  This is untested code so be sure and give it some pretty good testing.

Comment: I am not 100% sold on  `p.then(response => {` ... then deleting the entry. If something fails, then the failure should "cache" in my use case. I do wonder though, if  globalFetch is used as `await globalFetch(...)`, and  fetch fails with an error, will globalFetch() effectively throw and error?

Comment: I was also thinking of clearing up the cache each time a request is made... this is for a user app, so user interaction sounds like a good moment to do something like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240121/discussion-between-merc-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @Merc - That would work fine too, but you'd waste some cycles if you're traversing the whole cache on every request as that really isn't necessary, particular if the client is  making a bunch of requests in a row.  But, it's pretty cheap to iterate the cache so perhaps not really noticeable.

Comment: Request objects don't have own properties, your `makeHash` function would treat `globalFetch(url, new Request({ method: "POST", body }))` and `globalFetch(url, new Request({ method: "GET"}))` as the same request, it would also treat `globalFetch(new Request("/foo"))` and `globalFetch(new Request("/bar"))` the same.

Comment: The signature for the `fetch()` function is `const fetchResponsePromise = fetch(resource [, init])` That `init` is an object, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). You _can_ pass a `request` object as FIRST parameter (although I have never seen it done, and frankly I didn't even know you could do that, AND I don't know why you would do it to yourself...)

Comment: @Merc Request objects are also objects, they do work as second param too. Also, this function would even fail for Headers inside `init` (and even if only passed as a bare JS object). And the Request object is useful. When you or a coworker of yours will finally decide to implement a ServiceWorker and move all the network logic there, you will only deal with Request objects and this code will silently fail to do its job, certainly causing a few head scratches when it will actually cause a bug. And even outside of SW more APIs will consume and produce such Request objects in the future

Comment: @Merc - If it matters to you, this could be made to work with Request objects too with some extra code that would pull the relevant properties out of the Request object and use them in the hash.  I suspect that for your own use, you aren't creating Request objects yourself so perhaps not needed for your local use.

Comment: This is actually going to be a general purpose library. So, I will work towards a fully working solution that will work with request objects too.

Comment: But no, moving the logic to a service worker is 100% outside our radar for now. Improving this function, yes definitely.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful starting point. This module exists thanks to your answer (even though there close to none left of the original code proposed)  https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/spa-fetch/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @Merc - That link isn't working for me.

Comment: Apologies https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/spa-fetch/blob/master/spa-fetch.js

Comment: Ah it's you! Thank for opening the issue -- I implemented your request, and asked a question in the issue too :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) or [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) to separate caching logic from your application. The [Stale-While-Revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#stale-while-revalidate) strategy could apply here.

Comment: Would a "Stale-While-Revalidate" strategy allow for handling of "parallel" requests, i.e, to let a second synchronously executed request use the first one even if there is no response (or even even if the SW didn't even had time to just open the Cache?). I think OP is in the case `const r1 = fetch(req); const r2 = fetch(req);` and they want `r2` to not make a new network request.

Comment: Good observation, parallel request testing would definitely be needed.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, kinda weird there is nothing in the API to handle that already...